dbt debug on Microsoft fabric
I am trying to create a simple project using Fabric and dbt. I am following below tutorial:-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-warehouse/tutorial-setup-dbt
When i am executing dbt debug command , i am getting the below error
(.venv) PS C:\Users\trp\Workspace\Documents\Docs\Work\poc\apps-fabric-dbt\jaffle_shop> dbt debug
07:13:05  Running with dbt=1.8.1
07:13:05  dbt version: 1.8.1
07:13:05  python version: 3.9.5

07:13:05  os info: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
07:13:05  Using profiles dir at C:\Users\trp\.dbt
07:13:05  Using profiles.yml file at C:\Users\trp\.dbt\profiles.yml
07:13:05  Using dbt_project.yml file 
07:13:05  Configuration:
07:13:05    profiles.yml file [ERROR invalid]
07:13:05    dbt_project.yml file [OK found and valid]
07:13:05  Required dependencies:
07:13:05   - git [OK found]

07:13:05  Connection test skipped since no profile was found
07:13:05  1 check failed:
07:13:05  Profile loading failed for the following reason:
Runtime Error

  dbt encountered an error while trying to read your profiles.yml file.

  Profile jaffle_shop in profiles.yml is empty

My profiles.yml file looks like below:-
config:
  partial_parse: true
jaffle_shop:
  target: fabric-dev
  outputs:    
    fabric-dev:
      authentication: CLI
      database: db_trp
      driver: ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
      host: xxxyyzzzz.datawarehouse.fabric.microsoft.com
      schema: dbo
      threads: 4
      type: fabric

Can you please help me here? Thank You

Your profiles.yml file is having incorrect values. Cross check once again

Even I am getting the same error.


dbt encountered an error while trying to read your profiles.yml file:

I have also received the same error when I tried previously in my environment. After exploring on it, I found the issue is with the path of the profiles.yml file being created.
According to the dbt connection profiles document,

dbt checks your profiles.yml  file for a profile with the same name. Then dbt will search the current working directory for the profiles.yml file and will default to the ~/.dbt/ directory if not found.

So, make sure that you have created profiles.yml file in the folder where dbt_project.yml is present and passing the profile name correctly.
I have created it in the same folder with below format and was able to pass all the check connections.
profiles.yml:
jaffle_shop:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
     fabric-dev:
     authentication: CLI
     database: newwarehouseja
     driver: ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
     host: x6eps4xrq2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxu.msit-datawarehouse.fabric.microsoft.com
     schema: dbo
     threads: 4
     type: fabric

Note: Replace host, database names with your actual values correctly and also run az login before debugging the dbt.

Output:
dbt debug

dbt seed

dbt run

Refer MSDoc for setting up the dbt fabric.
